# How to return script tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, looker

I am trying to return a script tag in javascript.

```
export const MarketData = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>
         Market Data
      </p>
      {/* Script tag here */}
    </>
  )
}
```

The script tag looks like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-quotes.js" async>
  ...
</script>
```

Full code I am trying to embed can be found at: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/

How should I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just add a DOM element using JavaScript?

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). I suggest you ask how to include your script in the page instead.

Comment: @tadman I am trying to avoid doing that as I will need to unrender this chart based on different buttons clicked.

Comment: DON'T USE the `script` tag! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)